# How do I configure my .htaccess file for React App in Subdirectory?

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess

I want to host my react app in a subdirectory on my shared hosting account. Ie in the directory `domain.com/mydirectory/`. But when I type `domain.com/mydirectory/` in the search bar it opens the index of the directory & not the React App itself.

I have already created a build version for my app. Hence the index.html file is at the root of the directory with the static folder & all the other contents that where created during the `react-build` script.

How can I make it work properly ? How can I configure my .htaccess file or what fix should I consider ?

Answer (score 49):

You can try to add a `.htaccess` file in your React directory with that source code into it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: May be you will get a blank page because the server didn't find your static directory  modify the index.html file links like that /static/ to /subdirectory/static/.

Comment: Works like a charm :D but don't forget to uncomment the module in conf.  Ref. https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042

Comment: I am a front end dev. Any chance you guys would show the proper way to do this and force SSL? I've managed it before but have to search each time...thank you.

Comment: @MegPhillips91for ssl you can user certbot

Comment: @MegPhillips91 you can try using this command to redirect to https.
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

Answer (score 32):

Just copy and paste following in your `.htaccess`

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This `.htaccess` file worked for me. In my situation, I cloned the entire Git repository of a React project, not just the 'build' folder.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Serve files from the "static" directory directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ build/static/$1 [L]

# Handle client-side routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ build/index.html [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase you are using Nginx, the above .htacess method doesn't work. My context is deploying am app but with a react-vite app in a sub folder to an nginx server. Am using react router v6.20.

1. You need to configure your vite app well in the vite.config file.

```
export default {
  base: '/mydirectory',
}
```

2. Add the same basename in your react router configuration in your main.js. Mine looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import {
    createBrowserRouter,
    RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./routes/root";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import About from "./AboutPage";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
    [
        {
            path: "/",
            element: <Root />,
            errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "/about",
                    element: <About />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    {
        basename: "/mydirectory",
    }
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Make sure to replace "mydirectory" with your own.

3. Create a build.

```
npm run build
```

4. Go to your Ngnix file. Configure it this way in your nginx server block

```
location /mydirectory {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /mydirectory/index.html;
}
```

This is what worked for me using Nginx.