# 404 issue wtih react-router-dom v6 on vitejs build

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vite

Here is my code:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Container />,
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Home />,
        },
        {
          path: "/log-in",
          element: <Login />,
        },
        {
          path: "/contact",
          element: <Contact />,
        },
        {
          path: "/pricing",
          element: <Pricing />,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: "/contract-preview",
      element: <ContractPreview />,
    },
    {
      path: "/*",
      element: <NotFound />,
    },
]);
```

after `yarn build` and when I run code from `dist` directory (same situation is on the server) routes `/contract-preview` and `/*` are not reachable I am getting custom server 404 page isntead.

Versions:

```
"vite": "^4.0.3",
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.0.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

Vite config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()]
})
```

Do you have any suggestion how I can fix this?

Comment: The general gist is that whatever server you are deploying the app to needs to be configured to serve the root index.html file for any page request into your app. Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a broad overview how different server environments are configured differently. Perhaps there's already a section relevant to where you are deploying your app.

Comment: Did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090744/how-do-i-configure-my-htaccess-file-for-react-app-in-subdirectory actually resolve your question/issue?

Comment: This was the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090744/how-do-i-configure-my-htaccess-file-for-react-app-in-subdirectory

Comment: This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090744/how-do-i-configure-my-htaccess-file-for-react-app-in-subdirectory

Answer (score -1):

You should setup your web server to redirect 404 errors to your index.html file.

The idea behind a Single Page Application, is the web server always serve the same page. React-router handle the page display on the frontend side once the app loaded.

Comment: can you give me some examples? and why `/contract-preview` is showing 404?

Comment: When you go to your app on yourServer.com/contract-preview, nginx (or whatever the server technology you use) is looking for a file named `contract-preview`. Of course there is not and return 404 error. The behaviour you want is to return `index.html`. Your app load, react-router will parse `/contract-preview` in the url and display the right component.

Comment: Hey I did redirection added file `.htaccess` with content `ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/index.html` and now its working for NotFound. Thank you for that, but still for `/contract-preview` not working...

Comment: this is the response to my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090744/how-do-i-configure-my-htaccess-file-for-react-app-in-subdirectory