# Subpages doesnt work on hosting but works on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hosting

When i create build from react and put site on hosting subpages doesn't work (error 404) but when i test website on localhost everything works fine. Any ideas what can i do to make it works? Here is code for routing

```
import React from 'react'
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Interface, Main, LoginPage, Product, Solutions, Project, Teams} from './container/index'

const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/interface/*' element={<Interface />}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path='/*' element={<Main />}/>
        <Route path='/product' element={<Product />}/>
        <Route path='/solutions' element={<Solutions />}/>
        <Route path='/project' element={<Project />}/>
        <Route path='/team' element={<Teams />}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You need to have URL rewriting in place, that rewrites all direct requests for any such subpage URL to the /index.html On an Apache webserver, that would looks something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58442124/1427878 - do you have that? Is the mod_rewrite module active in your server configuration? (Or is it a different web server altogether?)