# How to make my react app run permanently in ec2?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I made a portfolio website with create react app and I opened an ec2 instance to run my website, when I'm using the ssh command "sudo npm start" afterward the site is running, but when I close down the ssh my website is not online anymore, How can I make my site run indefinitely?

Comment: will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50250307/how-to-deploy-create-react-app-in-aws-ec2

Answer (score 1):

You want to run this as a background service using systemd.

Try taking a look at: https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6.